# Pester - test variables parts of the :script scope fails

Tags: powershell

For the sake of learning Pester I'm running basic tests for a PS module I'm working on.

I basically mock one function to return a PSObject, and want to confirm the variable `$script:configuration` contains this object but fails. I can see from the test results that the mocked function works as expected as I just output the variable in Write-Host commands, but the test fails mentioning $null

I'm pretty sure it's linked to the script scope of the variable but can't figure out why or how.

Test failing

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 1 tests in 17ms.
Running tests.
BeforeAll - called
Initialize-SepmConfiguration - called
@{ServerAddress = RealServer01; port = 8446; domain = }
Initialize-SepmConfiguration - called
@{ServerAddress = FakeServer01; port = 1234; domain = }
[-] Initialize-SepmConfiguration.When the configuration file exist.Test Port
40ms (13ms | 27ms)
Expected a value, but got $null or empty.
at $script:configuration | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty, C:\GitHub_Projects\PSSymantecSEPM\Tests\zz_Initialize-SEPMConfiguration.Tests.ps1:36
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\GitHub_Projects\xxx\Tests\zz_Initialize-SEPMConfiguration.Tests.ps1:36
AfterAll - called
Initialize-SepmConfiguration - called
@{ServerAddress = RealServer01; port = 8446; domain = }
Tests completed in 1.7s
Tests Passed: 0,
Failed: 1,
Skipped: 0
NotRun: 0
```

My function

```
function Initialize-SepmConfiguration {
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

$script:configuration = Import-SepmConfiguration -Path $script:configurationFilePath
# Testing TODO remove Write-Host
Write-Host "Initialize-SepmConfiguration - called"
Write-Host $script:configuration
if ($script:configuration) {
    if ($script:configuration.ServerAddress -and $script:configuration.port) {
        $script:BaseURLv1 = "https://" + $script:configuration.ServerAddress + ":" + $script:configuration.port + "/sepm/api/v1"
        $script:BaseURLv2 = "https://" + $script:configuration.ServerAddress + ":" + $script:configuration.port + "/sepm/api/v2"
    }
} else {
    Reset-SEPMConfiguration
    }
}
```

My Pester test

```
Describe 'Initialize-SepmConfiguration' {
BeforeAll {
    # This is common test code setup logic for all Pester test files
    Write-Host "BeforeAll - called"
    $moduleRootPath = Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent
    . (Join-Path -Path $moduleRootPath -ChildPath 'Tests\Common.ps1')
}

AfterAll {
    # This is common test code teardown logic for all Pester test files
    Write-Host "AfterAll - called"
    Restore-SEPMConfiguration -Path $script:originalConfigFile
    $script:originalConfigFile = $null
}


Context 'When the configuration file exist' {
    BeforeAll {
        # Mock Import-SepmConfiguration
        Mock Import-SepmConfiguration -ModuleName $script:moduleName { 
            return [PSCustomObject]@{
                'ServerAddress' = 'FakeServer01'
                'port'          = '1234'
                'domain'        = ''
            }
        }
    }

    It 'Test Configuration Object' {
        # Call the function
        Initialize-SepmConfiguration

        $script:configuration | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here is also the Pester code i'm running on my Tests\Common.ps1 script. I'm basically building the module before each tests (because I'm changing it often) and backup real data before restoring it after all my tests

```
# The path to a file storing the contents of the user's config file before tests got underway
$script:originalConfigFile = $null

function Initialize-CommonTestSetup {
param ()

# init
$script:moduleName = 'PSSymantecSEPM'
$moduleRootPath = Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent
$BuildModuleSourcePath = $moduleRootPath + "\Source\PSSymantecSEPM.psd1"
$MajorMinorPatch = dotnet-gitversion | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Expand MajorMinorPatch
$importModulePath = $moduleRootPath + "\Output\PSSymantecSEPM\" + $MajorMinorPatch + "\PSSymantecSEPM.psm1"
$FullSemVer = dotnet-gitversion | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Expand FullSemVer

# Build & load the module
Build-Module -SourcePath $BuildModuleSourcePath -SemVer $FullSemVer
Import-Module -Name "$importModulePath" -Force

# Backup the user's configuration file before testing
# Will be restored after testing in "AfterAll" block
$script:originalConfigFile = New-TemporaryFile
Backup-SepmConfiguration -Path $script:originalConfigFile
}

Initialize-CommonTestSetup
```

Comment: Look at blank lines in output.  It indicates that Write-Host is outputting empty strings.  I like piping results to Format-List for debugging instead of Write-Host.  Format-List gives much better info.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I was the one who added those empty lines for clarify. They were not present originally

Comment: Seems like the issue is that you need to use `function global:Initialize-SepmConfiguration` or use a `.psm1` file and `Import-Module` at the top of your pester test file

Comment: The module is loaded via the "Common.ps1" file part of the BeforeAll block. I can also confirm the mocked function works because of the test output correctly showing "FakeServer01" which is what my mock returns. This is why it's baffling for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an afternoon of tinkering, I found the problem

As I am testing variables inside a module, there is a dedicated `InModuleScope` block to use. Looks like this

Pester documentation mentions it : https://pester.dev/docs/commands/InModuleScope

```
Describe 'Initialize-SepmConfiguration' {
    BeforeAll {
        # stuff ...
    }
    AfterAll {
        # stuff ...
    }

    InModuleScope 'MyModuleName'{
        Context 'When I run Initialize-SepmConfiguration' {
            BeforeAll {
                # Mock Import-SepmConfiguration
                Mock Import-SepmConfiguration -ModuleName $script:moduleName { 
                    return [PSCustomObject]@{
                        'ServerAddress' = 'FakeServer01'
                        'port'          = '1234'
                        'domain'        = ''
                    }
                }
            }

            It 'Test Port' {
                # Call the function
                Initialize-SepmConfiguration
    
                $script:configuration.port | Should -Be '1234'
            }
        }
    }
}
```